# How can I run a fake X server & link it to a specific GPU?

Tags: xorg, drivers, nvidia, graphics

On [this page](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?s=cfac626f1c9f948db9d106a33789cbff&showtopic=182896&pid=1131119&st=0&#entry1131119) the final post mentions Xvfb as a way to run a fake Xserver.

Is it possible to tie this directly to a specific card as if a display was attached??

Specifically, I'd like to [overclock my gpus](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7749/2696/), but short of that (since the Clock Frequencies tab won't make an appearance), I'd like to at least crank up the fan so that my CUDA kernels can run on a cooler gpu.  To do so within the driver framework, a display must be attached to the card.  *But if I do that, then I can't set the card to ["Compute Exclusive" mode](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/alt-nvidia-current-smi.1.html).*

Basically, does anyone know of a way to attach a fake (software based) display to a specific gpu in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should ask Nvidia for overclocking support outside the X driver (e.g. in that nvidia-smi tool).

Using a graphics driver that is not for your GPU is not useful, as it doesn't know anything about the hardware, and nvidia-settings only knows about the nvidia driver.