# Lowering Graphics and Processor Clock Nvdia GeForce 570

Tags: nvidia, graphics, xorg

My graphics card it's standard graphics and or processor clock setting is too high. It crashes sometimes.

On windows I used MSIafterburner to lower it a bit, but a google told me that MSIafterburner doesnt work on linux. I tried coolbits but I couldnt get that working properly. The xorg.conf doesnt like to be edited and it had trouble staying altered between reboots.

At the moment the Graphics Clock is 786 and the Processor Clock is 1572.
I'd like to change it to the values given by GeForce, 732 and 1464. And I'd really like the values to stay changed to what I set them at. Windows sneakily set them back to the old values every now and then, which was very annoying.

http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-gtx-570/specifications

Comment: This question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/7749/how-can-i-overclock-a-graphics-card-from-within-ubuntu is comparable to your question. It describes how to overclock while you want to lower the setting.

Comment: I already tried coolbits. I did look into it again. [info here](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?px=MTY1OTM&page=news_item) and [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NVIDIA/Tips_and_tricks#Enabling_overclocking). I did at one point (before posting this question) get the PowerMizer setting working, but I'm unable to recreate that at the moment. I'm pretty sure I need coolbits at 8. At the moment the xorg.conf is succesfully edited, in the right place, with what should be the right line of code, Option "Coolbits" "8", but when I open nvidia-settings the option does not appear.

Comment: I'll look into it again tomorrow.

Comment: Problem permanently fixed. The graphics card died, likely due that overclocking issue. Bought a new one.

Comment: Well, that's too bad that this is the outcome. Please answer your question with the information in your last comment and accept your own answer otherwise the question will remain as unanswered and then pop up regularly.

Answer (score 0):

Problem permanently fixed. The graphics card died, likely due that overclocking issue. Bought a new one.