# How to overclock Nvidia GPU in Linux

Tags: intel, xserver, amdgpu, nvidia-settings, amdgpu-pro

I'm trying to overclock my computer that has both AMD and Nvidia GPUs. I have the integrated graphics set as the primary display in BIOS to save GPU memory but when I do that it prevents X server from starting. I can still use the pc via ssh but can't overclock the nvidia cards without X server running. Is there a workaround for this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/7749/how-can-i-overclock-a-graphics-card-from-within-ubuntu or a bit newer: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1251920/overclock-nvidia-gpu-to-achieve-undervolting cool-bits is the tool to use.

Comment: Always include the version of Ubuntu in any question.