# Monitor powered by Nvidia GPU only shows wallpaper

Tags: drivers, gnome, graphics, xorg, gui

I have a Dell R720 home lab running Ubuntu 22.04. It is equipped with the following GPUs:

```
$ nvidia-smi -L
GPU 0: Tesla P40 (UUID: GPU-ac45b921-3664-d911-5dd7-e5b8d49551c3)
GPU 1: Tesla P40 (UUID: GPU-11fdf0e4-2c22-162a-a65e-f594c9a908ae)
GPU 2: NVIDIA GeForce GT 710 (UUID: GPU-6fabed11-9de9-cd98-3220-658b45c1e7e8)
```

I want to use the two P40s as CUDA compute cards and have the GT 710 run the desktop environment, but I have trouble setting up Xorg and/or Gnome. In particular, the GT 710 only outputs a wallpaper on the monitor, but I cannot see anything else: no mouse pointer or login window, and it doesn't respond to mouse movement or keystrokes. Like this:

[image]

How can I get a usable desktop environment?

---

The output of `nvidia-smi`

```
Tue Feb  6 17:32:33 2024
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 470.223.02   Driver Version: 470.223.02   CUDA Version: 11.4     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Tesla P40           On   | 00000000:04:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| N/A   28C    P8     9W / 250W |     22MiB / 24451MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  Tesla P40           On   | 00000000:42:00.0 Off |                  Off |
| N/A   29C    P8     9W / 250W |     38MiB / 24451MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   2  NVIDIA GeForce ...  On   | 00000000:44:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 50%   31C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    424MiB /  2002MiB |     N/A      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A     97708      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 22MiB |
|    1   N/A  N/A     97708      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 38MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The content in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 470.223.02


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "AutoAddGPU" "off"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Tesla P40"
    BusID          "PCI:4:0:0"
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "Tesla P40"
    BusID          "PCI:66:0:0"
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce GT 710"
    BusID          "PCI:68:0:0"
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I cannot paste the content in `~/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log` here because a post is limited to 30000 characters, but you can see it [on Pastebin](https://pastebin.com/fRB31p1k).

Comment: Maybe it is showing the wrong desktop (a blank one).  Click on the 9 dot icon at the bottom of the launch bar and the desktops are shown across the top, click on the one you want.

Comment: @ubfan1 The thing is, I cannot see the 9 dot icon or anything else. There is just a wallpaper. I mean, the only screen I have in `xorg.conf` is `Screen0`, so it's probably the only desktop?

Comment: Use shortcut keys. The default shortcut keys to switch between the workspaces are as follows: Default Shortcut Keys. Function. Ctrl + Alt + right arrow. (and left arrow). But both desktops should have the launcher.  Maybe change resolution lower?

Comment: @ubfan1 The shortcuts didn't work (no response from GUI). I cannot access the desktop environment and `xrandr` in an SSH session only gives me `Can't open display`, so I cannot change the resolution either :(

Comment: Does the wallpaper change if you change your wallpaper?

Comment: @DanielT I'm not sure how to change the wallpaper (there is no way to open "Settings" when it doesn't even respond to mouse and keyboard input). However, every once in a while the wallpaper changes automatically. From a jellyfish, to a bug on a flower, to some landscape, etc.

Comment: Ok, so the screen isn't frozen. Why do you have the Teslas in xorg.conf? If X11 works with them unplugged, removing their configuration should make them act like they were in a headless CUDA setup. Also try moving a window into the screen using Windows+Arrow

Comment: @DanielT You are right. Everything works correctly if I simply comment out the Teslas! If you make that into an answer I can upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the unnecessary and confusing inclusion of the non-graphical compute Tesla P40s in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 470.223.02
# Edited by https://askubuntu.com/questions/1502694


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "AutoAddGPU" "off"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

# Removed: 2 devices of Tesla P40 type

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "NVIDIA GeForce GT 710"
    BusID          "PCI:68:0:0"
    Option         "Coolbits" "28"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device2"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

CUDA GPUs can work headlessly, so they do not need to be exposed to X11. Your compute workload will talk to the Teslas directly, and not need to go through X11 on modern Linux. By removing the Teslas from the Xorg config, we keep X11 focused on the GT 710 used for display, and leave less room for things to go wrong.

Comment: As a follow-up question: how can I overclock the Teslas if they are not in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`? Every answer for [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7749/how-can-i-overclock-a-graphics-card-from-within-ubuntu) requires an entry for the GPU to be overclocked in `xorg.conf`.

Comment: The dumb/obvious way I would have approached that is putting them in xorg.conf then doing a `strace Xorg` to find the `ioctl`/`open` syscalls. However, I don't know how much work that would take or whether there's a cleaner solution

Comment: @nalzok Does the nvidia-xconfig solution work? https://askubuntu.com/a/1037178/1004020

Comment: Not really, because `nvidia-xconfig` works by editing `/etc/X11/xorg.conf`. If the two Teslas are not present in `xorg.conf`, then it cannot set their coolbits; if they are present, then we have the problem described above.